# How to avoid yellow screen of death during http modules initialization?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, iis-7.5, httpmodule

I have following http errors configuration:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Auto" defaultResponseMode="File">      
  <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />     
  <error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="Error.html" responseMode="File" />    
</httpErrors>
```

Also, errors are handled in Application_Error and `Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true` is set in there.

It works fine in regular cases, but if exception occurs in http module initialization during application startup (module is third party, can't modify it's behavior), yellow screen of death is shown. Problem is, that in such case it does not reach Application_Error event and for some reason httpErrors settings are ignored.

Is there any way to suppress yellow screen of death in this case, I can't use `existingResponse="Replace"` as it overwrites response even if `Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true` is used.

Comment: I would say `existingResponse="Replace"` is your only option. When using `Auto` the asp.net yellow screen is considered a valid response and is passed through. If you need to use `Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true` make sure to catch all exceptions in your modules and log them on the server.

Comment: I would like to have exception correlation id in error page to allow easier matching of log entry and actual error appearance, still can't believe that there's no way to have both.